# Google Translate not working on PC Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I have the following code:

```
     <div id="google_translate_element" style="height: 30px; width: 400px; background-color: red;"></div>
<p>this is some text </p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Which works fine on most browsers, but on Windows 7 Firefox (latest) it appears broken. I have tested this on a page all by itself (no css, js) and it's still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with the help of below link

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/957611

To Reset Firefox do the following:

- Go to Firefox > Help > Troubleshooting Information.
- Click the "Reset Firefox" button. Firefox will close and reset.
- After Firefox is done,it will show a window with the information that
  is imported.
- Click Finish. Firefox will open with all factory defaults applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  I tried a variety of Firefox resets, but with no luck.  I found a [blog post that pointed me in the right direction](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/01/26/google-translate-flashblock-firefox/).

The solution that worked for me was to **install Adobe Flash**.  For whatever reason, the Google Translate widget that loads within Firefox relies on Flash to load the language list.

If you use a tool like Firebug and watch the Network traffic, you'll see the following URL is loaded:

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/js/element/hrs.swf
```

Not sure what it's purpose is, or why other browsers like Google Chrome, or mobile browsers do not require this, but Firefox does.  So, in short, no Flash, no language list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox 34.0.5.
This will properly working in this version.